# logical or on list of pandas masks

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a list of boolean masks obtained by applying different search criteria to a dataframe. Here is an example list containing 4 masks:

```
mask_list = [mask1, mask2, mask3, mask4]
```

I would like to find the logical or of all of the masks in the list. In other words,

```
or_mask = mask_list[0] | mask_list[1] | mask_list[2] | mask_list[3]
```

Is there a compact way to accomplish this for a list containing an arbitrary number of masks? I understand that I can write a for loop as below, but is there a shorter, more pythonic way to do this?

```
for i in range(len(mask_list)):
    if i == 0:
        temp_mask_or = mask_list[i]
    else:
        temp_mask_or = temp_mask_or | mask_list[i]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use reduce:

`or_(x,y)` means `x|y` so this will work:

```
from operator import or_
or_mask = reduce(or_,mask_list)
```

Edit: As suggested by JoeCondron, instead of `operator.or_`  you could use `numpy.logical_or` which gives the same result but is faster.

Comment: I wasn't aware of these commands--thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: you can also use `numpy.logical_or` as opposed to `or_` which looks to be around 4 - 6 times faster.

Comment: I have built two masks, and one happens to contain a NaN, and is therefore considered of dtype object. Reducing the masks using `operator.or_` does as if the NaN was a False. Using `numpy.logical_or` makes the resulting mask being of dtype object and masking then results in a `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`. (I had initially tried `np.any(masks, axis=0)`, which results in the same error.)

Answer (score 2):

I normally use a similar loop to yours when combining masks, perhaps slightly differently:

```
combmask = mask_list[0]
for mask in mask_list[1:]:
    combmask |= mask
```

If that's not short enough, you can use the fact that you're only *or*-ing the masks, to your advantage, and treat them as ints (which they are under the hood):

```
combmask = np.array(sum(mask_list), dtype=np.bool)
```

If you look at `sum(mask_list)`, you'll find it's just a list of integers.

One possible caveat, what I don't know about the latter method, is whether it runs into problems when you try to sum more than 255 masks, where at least one (the same) element is always `True` (i.e., `1`). The underlying integer type to store the `np.bool` is only 8 bits afaik, and you would reach the integer limit that way. Perhaps numpy/Python automatically casts everything to a 16 bit integer type before proceeding, but I don't know that.

---

Edit: I'll leave the latter mention in, but it was easy to check:

```
In [51]: len(mask_list)
Out[51]: 4

In [52]: sum(mask_list).dtype
Out[52]: dtype('int64')
```

So even the sum of a short list of mask is converted to a 64 bit integer (which can then easily be converted to a boolean mask array), and you won't run easily into the integer limit.

Comment: Yes, I like your for loop much better. And very interesting about the mask just being a list of integers--I didn't know that.